# Disassembly a win Linux file

Tags: javascript, assembly

I have a file that has a compiled assembly code and being loaded into javascript code for execution.
How can I “inspect” the file? I am aware of tools like immunity debugger or ollydbg but I am not sure they can help me here.

How can I see or evaluate the contents of that file?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic since there is no obvious security aspect here. It seems to be better suited to [reverseengineering.se].

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but its iust a small question to get started.. Obviously a security geek have gone through such process during his pentesting regime

Comment: You basically answered your question yourself. `ollydbg`, `x64dbg`, `IDA Pro`, `radare2`, `Ghidra` - all these tools can help you.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information about your file... what format is the file actually in? ELF, PE, raw machine code etc.? How is javascript loading it?

Comment: assembly + javascript. Is it wasm?

Comment: What’s a “win Linux” file?